# wso2is - Adding new keystore

Tags: ssl, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to set up a new keystore in wso2is, I follow the 2 guides :

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN446/Creating+New+Keystores
- https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products

In the https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products it says to change keystore in `sec.policy`, but the file doesn't exist in IS 5.2.0

Although the guide don't talk about theses files, where the default keystore seem to be used :

- conf/identity/EndpointConfig.properties
- conf/security/secret-conf.properties
- conf/security/cipher-text.properties

I have a webapp calling wso2is, the keystore has been added in the JVM using `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/newkeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypassword`

When calling oauth2 endpoint (https://myinternaldomain:9443/oauth2/token) I got this error :

> TID: [1] [] [2017-01-10 13:30:14,505] @tenant1.com [1] [IS] INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying
>   Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {tenant1.com[1]} TID: [1] [] [2017-01-10
>   13:30:14,536] admin@tenant1.com [1] [IS]ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Error while
>   updating wso2carbon-sts in STSDeploymentInterceptor
>   java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was
>   incorrect
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
>           at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
>           at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.KeyStoreManager.getKeyStore(KeyStoreManager.java:146)

I did not change anything regarding keystore in the axis2.xml because all information regarding the keystore are commented.

All other endpoints (soap enpoints) are working fine with SSL, and everything works fine with localhost and default wso2carbon.jks 
but I cannot make oauth2/token endpoint work with a new jks.

Thanks for your input, ideas.
Regards

Comment: The document your are referencing to is of older version, can you try the following configuration: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Creating+New+Keystores

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding the public key in the java default keystore

`keytool -import -v -alias certalias -file newkeystore.pem -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit`

and by doing the following configuration which should definitely be in the wso2is keystore configuration documentation !

http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/11/05/how-to-changing-the-primary-keystore-of-a-tenant-in-carbon-products/